# formatting in visual studio won't fix indenting

Tags: visual-studio

I have a c# project that has indent formatting issues. And when I format a document  in the project the indenting isn't altered. Incorrect spacing is fixed so it seems the function is executed.

If I manually change the indentation formatting the document doesn't alter the indent to the old position. So it seems it just ignores indentation.
I have reset the visual studio setting and it doesn't help.
There is no .editorconfig file in the project directory
If I create a new project it does work.
Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 have the same issue.

Does anybody know any fix for this?